# VB.NET application crashes on my server if I start more than 5 threads

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, crash

As title, my VB.NET application crashes on my server if it has more than 5 threads when I run it on my server.

Let's say, I have 6 declared threads:

```
Dim Thread1 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf NoParametersSub1)
Dim Thread2 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf NoParametersSub2)
Dim Thread3 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf NoParametersSub3)
Dim Thread4 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf NoParametersSub4)
Dim Thread5 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf NoParametersSub5)
Dim Thread6 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf NoParametersSub6)
```

Then I start the first 5 threads and it works fine:

```
Thread1.Start()
Thread2.Start()
Thread3.Start()
Thread4.Start()
Thread5.Start()
```

Whenever I reach the part of the code where I start the 6th thread:

```
Thread6.Start()
```

The application crashes saying "(assembly name) has stopped working".

It crashes regardless I put a Try/Catch block, for example:

```
Try
    Thread6.Start()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

or:

```
Try
    Thread6.Start()
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

It just crashes.
As I can see in detailed crash information the exception is "System.InvalidOperationException".

As I can see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/fd85b3df.aspx
It says:

> An System.InvalidOperationException is thrown when a method of an
>   object is called when the state of the object cannot support the
>   method call.

So I have put

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
```

in order to wait for the thread to initialize properly (I guess?) then I tried again but it still crashes.
Then I read this:

> The exception is also thrown when a method attempts to manipulate the
>   UI from a thread that is not the main or UI thread.

but I'm not trying to manipulate the UI, unfortunately.

Then here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/6x4c42hc(v=vs.110).aspx

InvalidOperationException:

> This thread was created using a ThreadStart delegate instead of a
>   ParameterizedThreadStart delegate.

I don't need parameters in my thread but I tried anyway:

```
Thread6.Start(New Object() {})
```

but it still crashes.

Example of a crashing process:

> Problem signature:
>
> Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
>
> Problem Signature 01:   ProcessControlTest.exe
>
> Problem Signature 02:   1.0.0.0
>
> Problem Signature 03:   57cfbaee
>
> Problem Signature 04:   System
>
> Problem Signature 05:   4.0.30319.34003
>
> Problem Signature 06:   522ec39f
>
> Problem Signature 07:   3083
>
> Problem Signature 08:   2f
>
> Problem Signature 09:   System.InvalidOperationException
>
> OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
>
> Locale ID:  1033
>
> Additional Information 1:   5861
>
> Additional Information 2:   5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
>
> Additional Information 3:   bb02
>
> Additional Information 4:   bb02c3b29c3f075104f1d0629e885cfc

The server got Windows Server 2012 R2, the application has been compiled using .NET Framework 4.5.2, has 12 cores and 4 GB allocated to the process (has 32 GB of RAM overall).

I guess Windows Framework got corrupted in my server.

Thanks for help in advance.

Edit: **No matter what NoParametersSub6 contains, the program crashes as long as I start 6 threads**

Comment: The most basic issue here is that you have absolutely no idea where your program crashes.  And it is **not** where you think it is.  Every .NET programmer eventually discovers that writing an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event is never really optional.  You *must* have one so you can diagnose mishaps after the program is no longer in reach of a debugger.  The DebugDiag utility would be another way but it doesn't help the user solve the simple problems for you.

Comment: No matter what NoParametersSub6 contains, the program crashes as long as I start 6 threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed**.

.NET Framework was corrupted in my server.
I had to repair .NET Framework: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2698555

It's now working like a charm.

**Faster fix**: Go to **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[version]\SETTINGS**, delete the file named **machine.config** and rename **machine.config.default** to **machine.config**, then reboot your system and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping a try catch around thread.Start() won't help you. The exception is being thrown from within your method NoParametersSub6. An unhandled exception on any thread will crash an application. Put the try/catch in your sub with some logging

```
Private Sub NoParametersSub6()
    Try
        '... my stuff
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Thread Terminating:" & ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

You should have some sort of logging + Error handling with graceful exit on every thread start. Plus as Hans Prassant mentions you should handle `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` to catch any situations that you fail to wrap.

Comment: No matter what NoParametersSub6 contains, the program crashes as long as I start 6 threads.

Comment: It could be that whatever you're doing in thread6 is causing issues in another thread. Hence why you should have error handling on all threads and logging in the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event handler. Until you have logging you're flying blind and so are we.

Comment: I must repeat myself: No matter what NoParametersSub6 contains, the program crashes as long as I start 6 threads. Even if it's an empty Sub it crashes, as long as I try to start the 6th thread.

Comment: And I'll repeat myself. Put in logging.